# IPv6 enabled but cannot ping or make HTTP requests

Tags: ipv6, node.js

After being forced to use IPv6 for connections because of a CGN my ISP uses, I tried to set up a proof-of-concept node.js server to see if it was working. To note, this is my first time ever working with IPv6. Server code is extremely simple:

```
const HTTP = require('http');

HTTP.createServer((req, res) => {
    if(req.method == 'GET') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/plain' })
        res.write('Hello, world!');
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(7515);
```

From my understanding, I should be able to make an http request from a browser with my public IPv6 address like this `http://[2a02:2f08:a303:2700:b173:6af5:d01b:db61]:7515/` and it should output "Hello, world!" to the browser window, but it gives me an address is unreachable error from anything that isn't on my local network.

For reference, the test at https://test-ipv6.com/ returns positive for every mirror and my firewall has rules to allow traffic on that port I am using. Pinging from my local network works just fine, while trying to ping from any tool results in 0 packets received back.

Comment: This really appears to be a firewall problem. If you added the rule for the IPv4 firewall, did you add it for the IPv6 firewall, too? What about a firewall on the server itself? Also, because your ISP uses CGN, that means you have residential service, a clause in your residential contract forbids running services to the Internet, so the ISP may be actively blocking that. The correct way to do this is to get a business contract.

Comment: I added the rules for my OS firewall and for my router firewall for IPv6(it's actually an empty blacklist on my router firewall). Unfortunately, I do not know of any details about the contract with my ISP since I am not the one who made the contract, I am looking into it though(through support tickets since assistance operators in my country seem to be technologically illiterate).

Comment: Your IPv6 firewall is going to drop all outside-imitated traffic by default. You must add a rule to allow specific traffic. All the residential ISP contract have a clause forbidding running services to the Internet, and that is what business contracts are for.

Comment: Disabling firewall on router does not help, so I guess I have to contact my ISP regarding my contract and see what I can do, thank you for the response. Worth noting that a previous contract(which most likely wasn't a business contract) with the same ISP did allow me to do this though.

Comment: Your default route for IPv6 traffic ?

Comment: I do not know how to check my default route for IPv6 traffic and I can't find any information on how to do it, can you please tell me how?

Comment: Something like `ip -6 route` if you are on a Linux computer, or `route print` on a Windows machine.